# How to find the ratio of the microprocessor's rate in cycles per second to the update rate of a movie projector

Tags: notation, physics, mathematical-physics

I have tried scouring through my textbooks but am just not sure how to answer this.

A PC microprocessor runs at 2.40 GHz. A Hertz (Hz) is a unit meaning "one cycle per second." A movie projector displays images at a rate of 24.0 Hz. What is the ratio of the microprocessor's rate in cycles per second to the update rate of a movie projector? Answer the question using scientific notation.

Comment: if you shift the 2.4 by a factor of 10 does that help you think about it ?

Comment: G stands for Giga. Since the definition of Giga varies slightly with context you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giga- if you are unsure. I can't understand why you are asking this question when it is the  n graphics processors, working in parallel, that manipulate and send data to a screen or projector. The speed of the main/central microprocessor is of little or no relevance to this data pathway nowadays.